# Youtube embed with watch_popup and no suggested videos

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

Is it possible to embed a youtube video using the "watch_popup" method without suggested videos being shown at the end of the video (rel=0)?  I really like the "watch_popup" method because it shows the share buttons and the Youtube HD logo with HD videos.
Something like this should work... but it doesn't.

```
<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="650" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch_popup?;v=VIDEO_ID&rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

ref: http://illuminea.com/remove-related-videos-from-end-of-embedded-youtube-video/

Go to the video’s individual page on YouTube. In this case, the individual page is at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z8GHf-aELjY.

On the bottom of the video, click Share.

Once you click Share, a new area slides open underneath the video with a shortlink for sharing the video. It also presents an Embed button. Click that.

When you click Embed, another area opens up underneath that offers you the embed code, and also a number of options to allow you to customize the video’s appearance on your site. The first option is a checkbox that says “Show suggested videos when the video finishes.” Make sure that box is unchecked. If you look at the embed code, you’ll see that it adds a parameter after the video’s URL:

```
?rel=0
```

. “Rel” means related videos, and 0 is a binary command, meaning No.
image

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch_popup?.......
```

And you might also like this, so I thought I'd toss it in, if you want a quick embedded youtube:

Change the `watch?` part of the url to `watch_popup?`

Answer (score 0):

That's not an officially supported way of embedding YouTube videos. I'd recommend switching to the [iframe Player embed](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) instead as the player you're using might stop working at any time.

Answer (score 0):

after embed link give " ?rel=0&showinfo=0 " then it will avoid(disable) youtube suggested videos
thank you